# Grails Quartz startdelay doesn't work

Tags: grails, cron, quartz-scheduler

I'm using Grails 2.4.5 and [plugin quartz 1.0.2](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-quartz/guide/triggers.html). My job:

```
class NotWellpaidJob {
    def staticaService
    static triggers = {
        cron name: 'cronTrigger',startDelay:3000, cronExpression: "0/20 58 16 ? * MON-FRI"
    }

    def execute() {
        print new Date()
    }
}
```

My output:

```
Thu Nov 19 16:58:00 CET 2015
Thu Nov 19 16:58:20 CET 2015
Thu Nov 19 16:58:40 CET 2015
```

Question:

Why *startDelay* doesn't delay first execution by 3 seconds and the first datetime isn't **Thu Nov 19 16:58:03 CET 2015**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set a `startDelay` on a cron trigger, the plugin is essentially modifying what's being passed to `setStartTime` on the [CronTriggerImpl](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/impl/triggers/CronTriggerImpl.html) class in Quartz.

From the [Quartz documentation](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/previous_versions/2.1.0/org/quartz/impl/triggers/AbstractTrigger.html#setStartTime(java.util.Date)), the start time is defined as:

> The time at which the trigger's scheduling should start. May or may
>   not be the first actual fire time of the trigger, depending upon the
>   type of trigger and the settings of the other properties of the
>   trigger. However the first actual first time will not be before this
>   date.

So what you're setting is actually the delay of when the job is *scheduled*, not when it is *fired*. This doesn't actually change the fire time of the first execution.